# How to fix broken packages of linux unsigned image?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, apt

I am trying to setup an environment to build kernel, but it seems my package manager doesn't work.

My current Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

`uname -a` -> `Linux _ 5.15.0-67-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 22 14:14:39 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

The command

```
sudo apt-get build-dep linux linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

results in

```
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'linux-signed' as source package instead of 'linux-image-5.15.0-67-generic'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:linux-signed : Depends: linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-67-generic (= 5.15.0-67.74) but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: linux-generate (= 5.15.0-67.74) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

For more detailed information, I uncommented all deb-src lines then `sudo apt update` before I exec this install command. (I am not sure if this was the way to go)

My `etc/apt/sourses_list`

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates universe
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. I worked around it by running the following command instead:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep linux linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)
```

Note the extra "`-unsigned`". This may or may not meet your needs.

Comment: FWIW I ran into this same problem today, "apt-get build-dep linux linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)" runs into: "E: Unable to find a source package for linux-image-unsigned-5.19.0-32-generic" for me as of this writing.  Guess I need to upgrade kernel, but I've deliberately downgraded it because I'm in the process of trying to get a specific kernel module built/compiled/enabled and which hasn't been updated to later kernels yet... :|